# How can I Use autofilter in Excel if the person is occurring in two columns?

Tags: excel

I've a game schedule where I do the referee nominations - please see the file
I want to be able to filter the columns gym, date and referee. I know how to do that on gym and dates, with the Autofilter. My problem is the referees, because the same referee can appear in bot columns referee 1 and 2 . Can you suggest any solution to this problem?
My second question is: I want to list each referees partners, thought to solve this with Pivot table - is pivot table the best solution, or du you have any other solution?

Thanks in advance for your help
Peter

file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/p798eq4u89...lish.xlsx?dl=0

Comment: I didn't look at your file but a generic approach to "normalizing" this list is to put all referees in the same column and create another column for whether they're #1 or #2 in that instance. This generally make pivoting and other data analysis easier.

Comment: Thank you Doug for your answer! 
Could you please help me further?
- every games need 2 referees, and every referee have 2 games in row, and one game rest. Thats why I need 2 columns for referees #1 and #2
Could you please explain what you mean with:"put all referees in the same column "?
And how that will help my filtering?

Answer (score 1):

MY COMMENT: I didn't look at your file but a generic approach to "normalizing" this list is to put all referees in the same column and create another column for whether they're #1 or #2 in that instance. This generally make pivoting and other data analysis easier.

So again, I haven't looked at your sheet (because I'm careful that way) and unfortunately SO doesn't let you post a picture yet, so this is just how I'd do it based on your words:

[image]

To the left is the table and to the right the pivot. You can see the referee number column that I proposed in the table. I didn't use it in this version of the pivot, but I suppose it might be handy somehow. The pivot shows who's reffing what game and let's you see at a glance that there's two different refs per game, who they are, and that they're getting their days off.

Here's how I set up the pivot:

[image]

I hope that gives you some ideas.

Comment: Thx Doug for your answer! Unfortunately my columns are arranged in order: date, gym, referee 1, referee 2, only because it´s for me the easiest way to do the nominations. Can you give any suggestions, what I can do in this case?

Comment: Sorry, no, if you want to stick with that design filtering and pivoting, your two stated goals, both will be more difficult. Good luck.